# Datatables - Disable Button inside table depending on cell value

Tags: datatable, datatables

The Table has two columns "button" and "department".

```
var table = $('#ticketdata').DataTable({
{
data: "button",
name: "button",
className: "button",
},
{ 
data: "department",
name: "department",
className: "department"
},
```

The Buttons need to be disabled depending on the "department" Value.
For Example: where the department value is "2000001" the button needs to be disabled.

| Buttons | Departments |

| enabled |    200000   |

|disabled| 200001 |

|enabled | 100055  |

I also prefer it to disable it with Jquery!
My Try was that:

```
if($('#ticketdata').find('.department').val() == "200001") {
   $("#ticketdata").find('button[id=assigned_to]').addClass("disabled");
}
```

Actually it makes no sense because it needs to know the same row or something like that.

Any Help?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

http://live.datatables.net/vosahugu/1/edit

Found a Solution!

Inside the Table where the data is displayed you can see data from other cells with "full."